# Wordpress not rendering correctly & Multiple posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been stuck on this since last night and cant' figure out why the "Work" section of my wordpress doesn't show the the_title. Also, my "work" page is set to the "Work Page" template. Also, how would I go about having multiple posts on this page? Thanks!

http://www.listentotheway.com

```
 <?php 

 /*

Template Name: Work Page

 */


 get_header(); ?>

<p> This is the work.php file </p>

 <?php 

 $args = array( 'post_type'=>'work' );

 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"<?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_field( 'description' ); ?>
<hr>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p> customize later </p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: try `<?php $the_query->the_title(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it's still stuck.

Comment: You also need `if ( $the_query->have_posts() )`

Comment: I am not sure whether my first comment is right so try with and without, but my second comment is definitely right

Comment: I did get a little further with if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) . It shows "customize later." Still trying to mess with it so it shows the title and the hr tag.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To summarise my suggestion so far:

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"<?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php // the_field( 'description' ); ?>
        <hr>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p> customize later </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I have coded out the words `the_field`, there is no such native Wordpress function. Try my code an see what happens!

Comment: Thanks for the help @in God I Trust.  I'm going to have to go back to square one cause it isn't working for me. I'll post my answer when I figure it out. Take care.